# How to compute a value to pass into a primary constructor from an auxiliary constructor?

Tags: scala, constructor

I want to define an auxiliary constructor which should compute some value and use it in multiple parameters passed to a primary constructor. A natural way to express this would be to define local vals before calling the primary constructor, but this is not allowed by the language:

```
object Computed {
  def veryComplexComputation(x: Double) = math.sqrt(x) // imagine there is some much more complex computation here
}
class Computed(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
  def this(x: Double, y: Double) = {
    val derivedFromX = Computed.veryComplexComputation(x)
    val derivedFromY = derivedFromX * Computed.veryComplexComputation(y)
    this(x, derivedFromX, derivedFromY)
  }
}
```

An alternative is to repeat the computation, but with very complex computations this can be a problem (and it also leads to a code repetition):

```
class Computed(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
  def this(x: Double, y: Double) = {
    this(
      x,
      Computed.veryComplexComputation(x),
      Computed.veryComplexComputation(x) * Computed.veryComplexComputation(y)
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the solution I have provided is not bad, but if there is a better way, I will definitely be happy to learn it (and to accept it as an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best trick I know is to use a *third*, private constructor taking a tuple of the parameters for the primary constructor, together with a helper function in the companion object:

```
object Computed {
  def veryComplexComputation(x: Double) = math.sqrt(x) // imagine there is some much more complex computation here

  private def computeArgs(x: Double, y: Double): (Double, Double, Double) = {
    val derivedFromX = veryComplexComputation(x)
    val derivedFromY = derivedFromX * veryComplexComputation(y)
    (x, derivedFromX, derivedFromY)
  }
}

class Computed(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
  private def this(xyz: (Double, Double, Double)) =
    this(xyz._1, xyz._2, xyz._3)

  def this(x: Double, y: Double) =
    this(Computed.computeArgs(x, y))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to add a suitable factory method to the companion object:

```
object Computed {
  def veryComplexComputation(x: Double) = math.sqrt(x) // can be private, if you wish

  def apply(x: Double, y: Double): Computed = {
    val derivedFromX = veryComplexComputation(x)
    val derivedFromY = derivedFromX * veryComplexComputation(y)
    new Computed(x, derivedFromX, derivedFromY)
  }
}
```

then you can instantiate your `Computed` type the same way as for case classes, foregoing the use of "new":

```
scala> val comp = Computed(4.0, 9.0)
comp: Computed = Computed@4de4e24f
```

(You might also want to consider making `Computed` a case class anyway - particularly if is entirely, or even mostly, used as a container for data)

Comment: This is often nice, but it also comes with a drawback: you cannot use such factory method in constructors of derived classes.

Comment: @Suma Fair enough, in that (in my experience rather unusual) case, a variant incorporating `computeArgs` from @sjrd's answer could still work, giving you something like `class DerivedComp(w1: Double, w2: Double) extends Computed(Computed.computeArgs(w1, w2))` (noting that `computeArgs` would need to be public, or possibly package-private for it to be accessible here).

Answer (score 0):

One can (ab)use multiple parameter lists with default values, like this:

```
class Computed(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
  def this(x: Double, y: Double)(
    derivedFromX: Double = Computed.veryComplexComputation(x)
  )(
    derivedFromY: Double = derivedFromX * Computed.veryComplexComputation(y)
  ) = {
    this(x, derivedFromX, derivedFromY)
  }
}
```

This exploits the fact each parameter list can access parameters from previous lists. Just do not forget to provide the empty parameter lists when calling the constructor:

```
new Computed(1, 2)()()
```

Answer (score 0):

One can chain several auxiliary constructors, each of them performing one computation, using marker traits to distinguish between constructors to avoid overloading ambiguity.

```
object Computed {
  def veryComplexComputation(x: Double) = math.sqrt(x) // imagine there is some much more complex computation here

  private trait DerivedFromX
  private object DerivedFromX extends DerivedFromX
}

class Computed(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
  private def this(name: Computed.DerivedFromX, x: Double, derivedFromX: Double, y: Double) = {
    this(x, derivedFromX, derivedFromX * Computed.veryComplexComputation(y))
  }
  def this(x: Double, y: Double) = this(Computed.DerivedFromX, x, Computed.veryComplexComputation(x), y)
}
```